# Paperclip/Rails not reading ENV variables with AWS information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, paperclip

I am trying to use paperclip with S3 AWS. I have set the secret keys and bucket name in the .bash_profile but Rials/Paperclip cannot seem to read them as i get the following error when i try to upload an image in development...

'missing required :bucket option'

If i replace the ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] with the actual name, i then get the following...

'Missing Credentials. Unable to find AWS credentials'

Here is the set-up in the model...

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
        },
:s3_host_name => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

I have tried putting the credentials in the development config file in Rails but i have the same errors. Do i need to tell rails where to look for the ENV variables or am I doing something else wrong here? It seems others are having similar issues but i cannot find a solution.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the AWS bucket, key and key_id in a YAML file and in 'config/initializers', create a new file to read the YAML file contents and set the corresponding ENV variables. Don't forget to restart your rails server

Example

```
google_client =  YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root.join('config/google_client.yml')}")
ENV['GOOGLE_APP_NAME'] = google_client['APP_NAME']
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'] = google_client['CLIENT_ID']
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = google_client['CLIENT_SECRET']
ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SCOPE'] = google_client['CLIENT_SCOPE']
```

Typically, we do not push the aws info in Github commit but just ssh to the remote server and place the YAML file in the config folder in our Rails app. So only people who have access to your server can read your aws credentials and not all people even if they have Github access.

tell me if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. I have been told that using the secrets.yml to store the information causes problems later on as you will have to place it in the .gitignore file due to the sensitive data. Apparently deploying to heroku will be very difficult without the YAML file. This is why I have avoided using it. Is the example about suggesting that I can keep the keys in the ENV files but just pass them through the YAML file so that Rails can read them better. Is there a reason that rails cannot read these keys straight from the ENV correctly? Again, thanks for posting.

Comment: I think it works with bash_profile and bash_rc but I have never done it this way. For Heroku this should help https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Cool! I have just created a .env file in my root project directory, added the keys to that and it works! Just need to add that to the .gitignore and set the heroku config when i come to deploying the app. Thanks for the help with this, really appreciated!